Azure App Service Custom Backup to Firewall Enabled Storage Account not working as expected
We have a set of App Services, all integrated within a VNet.
Our Storage Account has Firewall enabled with access given to the Vnet in which all the App Services are integrated.
When I setup a Custom backup to a Container in the Storage account, with Backup/restore over virtual network option Enabled, the custom backup should work.

But it is not the case, it returns following error:

Storage access failed. The remote server returned an error: (403)
Forbidden.. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate.

It works only when I add all the Outbound IP Addresses of the App Service to the Storage account firewall whitelist.
Why is it so?

You can check the Storage Account; it should be in the same VNet and subnet. If both the App Service and the Storage Account are in the same network, you should be able to access the Storage Account from the App Service with VNet integration. I am able to configure custom backup in the App without adding the outbound IP addresses.

The App Service and Storage Account are integrated with the same VNet and subnet, and when I try to configure a custom backup in the App Service, it is working as expected. If you are still facing an error, you may follow the MS Doc

Did you add the Microsoft.Storage service endpoint to the App Service subnet?  Storage Account->>Firewall and virtual networks->>Service endpoints-->Add existing?

If you select the VNet and Subnet while creating the App Service and Storage Accountit will add automatically, if not selected you need to add a service endpoint and delegation in the subnet, like this

App Service subnet already has Microsoft.Storage Service Endpoint added.
Also, access to App Subnet is already allowed in the Storage firewall.

Do both the app service and the storage account reside in the same VNet? Also, check if any NSG rules are blocking the traffic.
Kindly share the APP service and Storage account network configuration images by editing the qns.

Yes the App Service Vnet is added in the Storage account firewall allow list.

You'll need to add a private endpoint to the storage account into the virtual network. Merely having firewall setup for the vnet won't work.

Okay but then what is the purpose of "Backup/restore over virtual network" option in Custom Backup config?  Also, the VNET integrated App services are able to use Storage account through Application code then what is the issue with Custom backup of the same App services?
Documentation around this does not mention Private Endpoint. Could you please elaborate?

Hi @AjinkyaBapat,  Kindly follow the MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup?tabs=portal#back-up-and-restore-over-azure-virtual-network for more details.


Azure App Service Custom Backup to Firewall Enabled Storage Account not working as expected.

To access the storage account from the App Service via a private network (VNet) for configuring the custom backup in the Storage account, it is not required to add IP addresses in the firewall rules. check the following below points.
Make sure to check that both the storage account and the app service are configured in the same VNet, and also check if the NSG rules are denying traffic.
I have created an App Service with VNet named 'App-vnet' and subnet named 'app-subnet' as below.

Created storage account with same Vnet and subnet as below.

When I try to access the storage account from the app, it's working, and I configured a backup in the storage account.

Reference: Back up and restore over Azure Virtual Network

This is working now.
